# IE10+ Nested 3d transforms inside overflow:auto are brake :hover behaviour

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, transform

I have a trouble with CSS 3d transforms on IE 10-11
Here is my simplyfied HTML structure:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    ...
    <li>Item 12</li>
</ul>
```

And following CSS:

```
ul {  
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fp3j5rr/1/)

The problem is that I can't style list items with `:hover` in IE - they are highlighting hardly ever
If we will set overflow to `hidden/visible`, or if we will remove any `transform` - then `:hover` will do.

Also, in other browsers works great.
And also, this is not related to `transform-style: preserve-3d`

What can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time I got solution for problem in my context.

The thing is that we have another aproach to rotate element right-to-left:

```
transform: scale(-1, 1);
```

And this approach uses 2d transformation instead of 3d.
That fixes problem in IE.

[JSFiddle - Fixed for IE](http://jsfiddle.net/5fp3j5rr/4/)

But if you try to open above fiddle in Chrome *(i used version 42 dev-m)* - you'll see wrong rendered scrollbar. To fix it - just add zero translation hack to all elements that you rotate *(to move this elements on separate layer)*

```
transform: scale(-1, 1) translate3d(0,0,0);
```

[JSFiddle - Fixed for Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/vpotravnyy/5fp3j5rr/5/)

**But this, again, will return problem in IE!**
So I had to use browser detection here

> P.S. But bug in IE rendering engine is still valid. This is just
> workaround for particular problem.
>
> P.S.S. And also bug in Chrome rendering engine